# can anybody help me solve this?

Tags: geometry

Compute the distance between the point $M=(1,0,0,0)$ and the line $q$ ,where

$$ q: x=3-2t ,\quad y=3 ,\quad z=-1+2t ,\quad w=1+t. $$

Comment: I would like to know if you have made any effort to solve the problem..

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful to state what your thoughts and attempts on the problem are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: well the distance between [1,0,0,0] and [x,y,z,w] = $\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^9 + z^2 + w^2} = \sqrt{(2-2t)^2 + 9 + (-1+2t)^2 + (1+ t)^2}$ so find the $t$ where that value is smallest (use max/min calculus).  Or you know the shortest distance is a perpendicular.  Or there should be a formula to remember.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**
There is an explicit geometric approach you can use, projecting the point on the line, which is straight-forward.

Alternatively, here is an outline of an algebraic approach from first principles. You need to minimize (the square of) the distance between the point and the line, which is 
$$
f(t) = (3-2t-1)^2 + 3^2 + (2t-1)^2 + (1+t)^2
$$
which is clearly a parabola opening up, so its vertex is the minimum as you need. Can you simplify $f$ and find its minimum?

(For simplicity, recall that the $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabols $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is at $x = -b/(2a)$)

Comment: Nice hints without giving the answer.  +1

Comment: @fleablood i try... it sometimes feels like people come here to get others to do their homework for them :(

Answer (score 2):

The line is $p(t) = at+b$ where $a =[-2,0,2,1]$ and $b=[3,3-1,1]$.

We need a point $p(t)$ such that $M-p(t)$ is perpendicular to $a$, which is the direction of the line. So, multiply $M-p(t)$ and $a$ and that should be zero. $$a\cdot(M-p(t))=0$$

We get $a\cdot M = a\cdot a t + a\cdot b$.

Therefore $t = \frac{a\cdot M - a\cdot b}{a\cdot a}$. Since $M=[1,0,0,0]$ those products are very easy to compute.

$t =\frac{(-2\times 1 + 0\times0 + 2\times0+1\times 0) -(3\times1+3\times0+(-1)\times0+1\times0)}{(-2)^2+0^2+2^2+1^2} = -5/9$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

Let the point be $p(t) \in \mathbb{R}^4$.

Then the distance for a given $t$ is $\|p(t)-M\|$, but it makes it 
easier to minimise the square of the distance since that is a quadratic
in $t$.

So, compute $s(t) = \|p(t)-M\|^2$ and find the value of $t^*$ such that
$s'(t^*) = 0$. Then the minimum distance will be $\|p(t^*)-M\|$.

Comment: Please explain the downvote?

Comment: i don't understand it either -- up-voted for compensation :)

Comment: @gt6989b: Thanks :-)!